# Drawing angles/arcs in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Is there an easy way to draw the angle between two lines, i.e. a circular arc in inkscape?

Ideally it should be as easy as selecting both lines and clicking a button or something. I am not (yet) interested in measuring or drawing angles of specific size, only interested in the drawing part.

If that's not possible in inkscape, is there another good and free program that does vector graphics and angles?

I am currently using GeoGebra for that, but it is a bit clumsy for creating graphics, and in fact I often end up starting with GeoGebra for the angles and importing the file into inkscape for completion.

Comment: One fast method to draw an arc inside an angle can be found here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115755/how-to-create-vector-physics-diagram-with-know-angles-and-line-proiection The method isn't exact, but surely ok for illustrations

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the simplest way to draw an arc is draw a circle and grab the round handle on the left (using Edit paths by nodes tool) and drag either way, you can also use the angles in the menu bar dialogue.then you can rotate and size it when selected with the selection tool to fit. to return to the ark length double click or select the circle icon or the node tool when selected, hope that helps let me know if you need any clarification

[image]

if you select shift when you draw the circle and put it on the apex of the 2 lines you can drag the circle from that point [image]

Answer (score 4):

More options for creating angles with Inkscape:

1. (precise, less interactive, with guides)
   [image: angle with guides]
2. (imprecise, but very flexible and interactive, with measure tool)
   [image: angle with measure tool]

Comment: Guides are definitely better than the measurement tool for precise values (would be cool to be able to do that). The measurement tool can be transformed into guides, which could form a nice 3rd option.